# Slack SDK: How to add color to blocks similar to attachments

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'd like to know how to add color to slack blocks similar to attachments. In attachments I can add a color and the whole block will have a color line to the left which refine the way job output is reported.

I can do it in attachments using this code line below:

```
attachments=[{"color": "#FF0000" if errors else "#4BB543", "blocks": blocks}]
```

I want to use blocks instead as I have a file url to share and it's not rendering properly in attachments, but working well if I used blocks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://api.slack.com/messaging/attachments-to-blocks#direct_equivalents

> There is one exception, and that's the color parameter, which currently does not have a block alternative. If you are strongly attached () to the color bar, use the [blocks parameter](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/attachments#fields) within an attachment.